# In Quorum, between Raft and Istanbul BFT (IBFT) consensus, which has a better (faster) block confirmation time? Assuming Ceteris Paribus

Tags: quorum, ibft, raft

In Quorum, to help decide between Raft and Istanbul BFT (IBFT) consensus, which has a better (faster) block confirmation time? Assuming Ceteris Paribus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quorum's raft implementation is specifically designed for the speed of txn processing and confirmation, thus Raft mode is going to be much faster than IBFT.

Answer (score 4):

This paper [Performance Evaluation of the Quorum Blockchain Platform](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.03421) gives a good comparison between Raft and IBFT in term of latency and throughput.

Comment: This should be an accepted answer, since in conclusion they claim:


"RAFT and IBFT are comparable in terms of throughput except that RAFT performs slightly better at higher input transaction rates above 1650 tx/sec and IBFT slightly over performs RAFT for lower transaction rates, quite contrary to our expectation."

Comment: Yes, that's correct.